# Spring Security custom authentication provider's authenticate() method is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I followed the article [Using Custom Authentication Provider Spring Security](https://frugalisminds.com/using-custom-authentication-provider-spring-security/) adding a custom authentication provider in Spring Security.

I found that if I POST to /login, it is redirected to /login.

My custom Authentication Provider's authenticate() is not called.

Even if I use Spring Security's `TestingAuthenticationProvider`, POST to /login still get redirected to /login.

Is there some thing wrong with my WebSecurityConfigure? This is my configure.

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

I use Spring Boot. Do I need to modify the application.properties file? Is there any working sample project on using custom authentication provider?

Comment: I found the following log message:
Invalid CSRF token
Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
```

in your WebSecurityConfigure?

You will get a generated login-window that is using your CustomAuthenticationProvider as soon as you are trying to call a page you have not included in

```
.antMatchers("/", "/webjars/**").permitAll().
```

Comment: Even using the helloworld sample at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/boot/helloworld/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/samples/config/SecurityConfig.java I still cannot get authenticated. Already sent back to the login page.

Comment: @user13254659 Can you put logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG into your application.properties and provide the relevant part of your log?